# yii migration return 1215 mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, migration

After searching and checking my code over & over, now I want to ask.
I have 2 table `umessage` and `ureply`, when I want to add foreign key from `ureply` refrence to `umessage` I got 1215 mysql error.

Codes in file `m140602_080318_create_table_umessage.php` which create `umessage` table:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    /*
     * Create table umessage, this is connection way between customer & seller about specific object
     * Add foreign key to table user and it's column id with sender column
     * Add foreign key to table object and it's column id with objId column
     */
    $this->createTable('tbl_umessage', array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'time' => 'INT(15) NOT NULL',
        'body' => 'TEXT NOT NULL',
        'status' => 'TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0',
        'visibleToS' => 'TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0',
        'visibleToR' => 'TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0',
        'sender' => 'INT(11)',
        'objId' => 'INT(11) NOT NULL',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci');
}
```

And codes in file `m140602_080329_create_table_ureply.php` which create `ureply` table:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    /*
     * Create table ureply which store all replies to exact message
     * Add foreign key to table umessage and it's column id with msgId column
     */
    $this->createTable('tbl_ureply', array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'time' => 'INT(15) NOT NULL',
        'body' => 'TEXT NOT NULL',
        'isSender' => 'TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0',
        'msgId' => 'INT(11) NOT NULL',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci');

    $this->addForeignKey('fk_ureply_umessage', 'tbl_ureply', 'msgId', 'umessage', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
}
```

1215 error is for adding `fk_ureply_umessage` foreign key and I can't find my goofs.
Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: please list all table schemas inclusion of table which are used in addForeignKey method too

Comment: I list tables which are useful to solve the problem, because I just get error while adding `fk_ureply_umessage` which makes a relation between **ureply** and **umessage**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in `addForeignKey` method:

```
$this->addForeignKey('fk_ureply_umessage', 'tbl_ureply', 'msgId', 'umessage', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

the table that the foreign key references to should be `tbl_umessage` not `umessage`:

```
$this->addForeignKey('fk_ureply_umessage', 'tbl_ureply', 'msgId', 'tbl_umessage', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to foreign key references check the data type is equivalent between the foreign key and its reference

Comment: Thanks but I checked before and now again, both of them are `INT(11)`